# Possible mistake in this proof from textbook

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

The textbook gives this proof to show the continuity of $f(x)=x^2$ using the epsilon delta definition.

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)| = |x^2-x^2_0|= |x-x_0| \cdot |x+x_0|$$

Now they know from the definition $ |x-x_0| < \delta $

$$|x-x_0| \cdot |x+x_0| < \delta \cdot |x+x_0|$$

Because they want to eliminiate the $x$, since delta is not allowed to depend on x, they estimate that

w.l.o.g $$ \frac{x_0}{2} < |x| < \frac{3x_0}{2} $$

substitute $\frac{3x_0}{2}$ for $x$ and finish the proof from there.

**The estimate is not valid, since $x^2$ is defined for $x=0$ and therefore the equality does not always hold. They even said a couple paragraphs ago, that this kind of estimate does not work if the function is defined for $x=0$.**

**Is the textbook wrong or what am I not seeing?**

Comment: Since you've put $$\frac{x_0}{2} < |x| < \frac{3x_0}{2}$$ in the question, have the author assumed that $x_0 \ge 0$?

Comment: Translated into english, the book just says before the proof: Now we want to show the continuity of $f(x)$ using the estimate we've also used in the previous proof. And then the proof is given. But even so, if he assumed $x_0 \geq 0$, he would not have shown continuity for the whole $\mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: We cannot  guarantee that $x\pm x_0\ne 0,$ so $|x-x_0|<\delta$ only implies  $|x-x_0|\cdot |x+x_0|\leq \delta |x+x_0|.$... Also there is no reason, for a given $\epsilon >0,$  that $\delta$ should not depend on $x.$  If for each $\epsilon,$ we can find a  $\delta$ that works for all $x,$ the function is called uniformly continuous...  And $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous on $\mathbb R,$  but not uniformly continuous.... And your final remarks about  $x=0$ are logical.

Comment: @user254665: I think you are mixing $x $ and $x_0$. The $\delta $ will depend on $x_0$, but it cannot depend on $x $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the author has taken $\delta = \min\left\lbrace\dfrac{\lvert x_0\rvert}{2},\dfrac{2}{5\lvert x_0\rvert}\varepsilon\right\rbrace$, giving us
\begin{align}
\left\lvert\lvert x\rvert-\lvert x_0\rvert\right\rvert \le \lvert x-x_0 \rvert <& \frac{\lvert x_0 \rvert}{2} \\
-\frac{\lvert x_0 \rvert}{2} < \lvert x\rvert-\lvert x_0\rvert <& \frac{\lvert x_0 \rvert}{2} \\
\frac{\lvert x_0 \rvert}{2} < \lvert x\rvert <& \frac{3\lvert x_0 \rvert}{2},
\end{align}

which is the range of $x$ in the question.  **This estimate is not valid when $x_0 = 0$ since $\delta = 0$, but in the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition for limits/continuity, we require $\delta >0$.**  That's why the estimate $$\bbox[5px,border:solid red 1px]{\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon {2|x_0|+1}\right\}}$$ in another answer is *better* due to the absence of $x_0$ in the numerator, so *the choice of $\delta$ is not affected even if $x_0 = 0$*.

If $x_0 \ne 0$, we have $\lvert x\rvert > \dfrac{\lvert x_0 \rvert}{2} > 0$.  If $x_0 = 0$, we can't do the same to conclude $\lvert x\rvert > 0$.

- We have $\lvert f(x)-f(x_0)\rvert = |x-x_0| \cdot |x+x_0| < \delta \cdot |x+x_0|$, and
- we want $\lvert f(x)-f(x_0)\rvert < \varepsilon$, so it suffices to set an upper bound for $\lvert x + x_0 \rvert$.

$$\lvert x + x_0 \rvert \le \lvert x \rvert + \lvert x_0 \rvert \le \frac{3\lvert x_0 \rvert}{2} + \lvert x_0 \rvert < \frac{5\lvert x_0 \rvert}{2},$$

Thus we have

$$\lvert f(x)-f(x_0)\rvert < \delta \cdot |x+x_0| < \delta \cdot \frac{5\lvert x_0 \rvert}{2} \le \varepsilon,$$

ending the proof for $x_0 \ne 0$.

**Another problem in the above proof is obvious**: when $x_0 = 0$, we can't define $\delta$ as above since $\dfrac{2}{5\lvert x_0\rvert}\varepsilon$ is **undefined**.  That's why we usually add a $1$ to the denominator in textbooks: $\delta = \min\left\lbrace\dfrac{\lvert x_0\rvert}{2},\dfrac{2}{5\lvert x_0\rvert + 1}\varepsilon\right\rbrace$.

$$\lvert f(x)-f(x_0)\rvert < \delta \cdot |x+x_0| < \delta \cdot \frac{5\lvert x_0 \rvert}{2} \le \frac{2}{5\lvert x_0\rvert + 1} \varepsilon \cdot \frac{5\lvert x_0 \rvert}{2} < \varepsilon$$

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit that I don't see where your book is going.

Since making $\delta $ smaller will not hurt you, you can prescribe $\delta \leq1$. Then  $|x|<|x_0|+1$, and so $|x+x_0|<2|x_0|+1$. If you now choose  $$\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon {2|x_0|+1}\right\}, $$ you get $|x^2-x_0^2|<\varepsilon $ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta $.

Comment: They essentially did the same thing, only that they said $$\delta \cdot |x+x_0| < \delta \cdot ( \frac{3x_0}{2} + x_0 )$$ . From there on, you can choose delta to be $\delta:= min\{\frac{3x_0}{2},\frac{\epsilon*2}{5* x_0}\} $ Only that your estimate is valid, while theirs is not ( I think )

Comment: Could you explain, why you have to choose  $$\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon {2|x_0|+1}\right\} $$ instead of just saying $ \delta =\frac{\varepsilon}{2|x_0|+1} $

Comment: To set up an upper bound for $|x+x_0|$ in the first sentence of the answer, the inequality $|x|<|x_0|+1$ has been used, so we need to set $\delta \le 1$.

Comment: @plsmakemedomath: if you choose as you say and $\delta>1$, the estimate will not be valid.